# Sort directories before files and underscore first with ls

Tags: linux, directory, ls, filenames

When using 'ls' i want to sort directories first and then all files AND sort directories/files with underscore first. Here is an example:

```
_folder2
folder2
_file2
file
```

I can sort directories first with

```
ls --group-directories-first --color --ignore=lost+found
```

but the underscore at the beginning is ignored. Sorting underscore at the beginning works with

```
ls -d _* [!_]*
```

but both doesn't work together. I have tried a lot of combinations of the two commands, nothings works as i want it to work. sometimes the color is lost (whats important for me) or i have the subfolders and files of the directores instead of the folder name.

Also LC_COLLATE=C and LC_LOCALE=C doesn't work.

Comment: `LC_COLLATE=C ls --group-directories-first` should work as long as the `LC_ALL` env var is not set. `LC_ALL=C ls --group-directories-first` would always work but cause the error messages to be output in English.

Comment: No luck here. Don't work with LC_COLLATE=C or LC_ALL=C.

Comment: Note that it's not `LC_ALL=C; ls ...`, it's `LC_ALL=C ls ...` (or `LC_ALL=C; export LC_ALL; ls`, but that would mean setting the locale to `C` for every command, not just `ls`), or with `csh`/`tcsh`/`fish` `env LC_ALL=C ls ...`

Comment: `ls -d _* [!_]*` wouldn't make a difference because `ls` still sorts the file list. You'd need `ls -Ud -- _* [!_]*` (assuming GNU `ls`) to disable that sorting.